# Extract an emotion data frame

Tags: r, tidyr

Using tidy verse how is it possible to extract a dataframe with 5 columns of the emotion sadness, anger, joy, love neutral?

Example of expected output

```
id text sadness anger joy love neutral
11 "bad movie" 1 0 0 0 0
12 "good movie" 0 0 1 0 0
```

what I tried until now:

```
library(tidyr)
text = data.frame(id = c(11,12), text=c("bad movie","good movie"))
nrc_lexicon <- get_sentiments("nrc")
```

Comment: Hi, if you can specify what do you'd like to have different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52576238/extract-emotions-calculation-for-every-row-of-a-dataframe/52576810#52576810) it's going to be easier to answer.

Answer (score 0):

`tribbles` are nice

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
~id, ~text,       ~sadness, ~anger, ~joy, ~love, ~neutral,
11,   "bad movie",   1,       0,      0,      0,    0,
12,   "good movie",  0,       0,      1,      0,    0)

df

#> # A tibble: 2 x 7
#>      id text       sadness anger   joy  love neutral
#>   <dbl> <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1    11 bad movie        1     0     0     0       0
#> 2    12 good movie       0     0     1     0       0
```

```

<sup>Created on 2018-09-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: sorry but I think you misunderstand my question. I ask how I can make emotion analysis