# Extract emotions calculation for every row of a dataframe

Tags: r, text-mining, tidyr, sentiment-analysis

I have a dataframe with rows of text. I would like to extract for each row of text a vector of specific emotion which will be a binary 0 is not exist this emotion or 1 is exist.
 Totally they are 5 emotions but I would like to have the 1 only for the emotion which seem to be the most.

Example of what I have tried:

```
library(tidytext)
text = data.frame(id = c(11,12,13), text=c("bad movie","good movie","I think it would benefit religious people to see things like this, not just to learn about our home, the Universe, in a fun and easy way, but also to understand that non- religious explanations don't leave people hopeless and",))
nrc_lexicon <- get_sentiments("nrc")
```

Example of expected output:

```
    id text sadness anger joy love neutral
11 "bad movie" 1 0 0 0 0
12 "good movie" 0 0 1 0 0
```

Any hints will be helpful for me.

Example to make it for every row what is the next step?
 How can I call every line with the nrc lexicon analysis?

```
for (i in 1:nrow(text)) {
(text$text[i], nrc_lexicon)
}
```

Comment: The input and expected ouput are the same

Comment: @akrun I am sorry I updated it

Comment: are you asking how to loop through the data frame and apply the lexicon on each row?

Comment: @ghub24 apply the lexicon in every row and extract 1 for the emotion exist most

Comment: @Kkyr is ur text always limited to "bad movie" "good movie"? are u also looking an answer for how to find matches in your text and the sentiment table? in that case you would have to give more examples, I am assuming u are only looking for a way to merge your data

Comment: @ghub24 sorry but I am afraid I can't understand you. I don't need to merge my data

Comment: from what I understood the question asks about how to apply the lexicon in each row. This would be easy if the text in "text" data frame exactly matched the data in nrc_lexicon, which is not the case. Then we would have to do some pre-processing on the text, which depends on the type of data that you have under text. For eg: "Good movie"  has no corresponding row in "nrc_lexicon" but "good" has. So its easy to give an answer using "good". are u looking for that? and what do u mean by "most"? "good" has 5 emotions associated with it in "nrc_lexicon" which one do you want?

Comment: @ghub24 I would like to extract the sentiment of the whole sentence. From the 5 I mention in the example output I would like to keep the emotion with the best score and in the output results receive 1 the emotion which has the highest score and 0 the other emotions even if they exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
library(tidytext)   # library for text
library(dplyr)

# your data
text <- data.frame(id = c(11,12,13),
 text=c("bad movie","good movie","I think it would benefit religious
 people to see things like this, not just to learn about our home, 
the Universe, in a fun and easy way, but also to understand that non- religious
 explanations don't leave people hopeless and"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)  # here put this option, stringAsFactors = FALSE!

# the lexicon
nrc_lexicon <- get_sentiments("nrc")

# now the job
unnested <- text %>%
             unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%  # unnest the words
             left_join(nrc_lexicon) %>%     # join with the lexicon to have sentiments
             left_join(text)                # join with your data to have titles
```

Here the output with the `id`, you can have it also with the titles, but I did not put it due the long third title, you can easily put it as `unnested$text` in place of `unnested$id`:

```
table_sentiment <- table(unnested$id, unnested$sentiment)
table_sentiment
     anger anticipation disgust fear joy negative positive sadness surprise trust
  11     1            0       1    1   0        1        0       1        0     0
  12     0            1       0    0   1        0        1       0        1     1
  13     0            1       0    1   1        2        3       2        1     0
```

And if you want it as `data.frame`:

```
 df_sentiment <- as.data.frame.matrix(table_sentiment)
```

Now you can do everything you want, for example, if I remember well, you want a binary output if exist or not a sentiment:

```
df_sentiment[df_sentiment>1]<-1
df_sentiment
   anger anticipation disgust fear joy negative positive sadness surprise trust
11     1            0       1    1   0        1        0       1        0     0
12     0            1       0    0   1        0        1       0        1     1
13     0            1       0    1   1        1        1       1        1     0
```